# Need help with setting multiple array values to null in a loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, select, loops, null, for-loop

I have been working on creating a custom script to help manage a secret questions form for a login page.  I am trying to make all the seperate select lists dynamic, in that if a user selects a question in one, it will no longer be an option in the rest, and so on.  Anyways, the problem I am having is when I try to set the variables in the other lists to null.  I am currently working with only 3 lists, so I look at one list, and find/delete matches in the other 2 lists.  Here is my loop for deleting any matches.

```
for(i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
    if(array2[i].value == txtbox1.value) {
        document.questions.questions2.options[i] = null
    }
    if(array3[i].value == txtbox1.value) {
        document.questions.questions3.options[i] = null
    }
}
```

This works fine if both the matches are located at the same value/position in the array.  But if one match is at array1[1] and the other match is at array3[7] for example, then only the first match gets deleted and not the second.  Is there something I am missing?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: make sure you semicolon properly (";" after each "null") and also use "===" for comparison so you don't doing any unintended type coercion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see too many choices here, considering that the position in each array can vary.

Do it in separate loops, unless of course you repeat values in both arrays and share the same position

**EDTI** I figured out a simple solution, it may work, create a function. How about a function wich recives an array as parameter.

Something like this:

```
function finder(var array[], var valueToFound, var question) {
     for (i=0; i<array.lenght; i++) {
          if (array[i].value == valueToFound) {
                switch (question) {
                      case 1: document.questions.questions1.options[i] = null;
                              break;
                }

                return;
          }
     }
}
```

I think i make my point, perhaps it can take you in the right direction

Comment: I did try that earlier, seperating it out into two for-loops and still, the first array value is nulled but the second still remains.. also, i was hoping to do it in one loop, simply because i eventually would like to add more than 3 select lists and having a loop for each one would slow it down...

Comment: thanks for the reply! i hadn't thought of trying this, but I will go ahead and put this in and see if i can make it work..ill post back with my results

Comment: @Brett Check out my fast solution, it may help you out

Comment: amazing...added that switch function and tweaked a little bit to match my data and it worked like a charm! thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Brett Congrats, glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that the code isn't getting to `array3[7]` because either it doesn't exist or that `array2` is too short and you're getting a JavaScript exception that's stopping the code from doing the check. Is it possible that `array2` and `array3` are shorter than `array1`?

It is more code, but I would do it like this:

```
var selectedvalue == txtbox1.value;
for(i=0; i<array2.length; i++) { // iterate over the length of array2, not array1
    if(array2[i].value == selectedvalue) {
        document.questions.questions2.options[i] = null;
        break; // found it, move on
    }
}
for(i=0; i<array3.length; i++) {
    if(array3[i].value == selectedvalue) {
        document.questions.questions3.options[i] = null;
        break; // you're done
    }
}
```